# e2e Tests Failing in Codeship but not Locally

Tags: angularjs, heroku, protractor, codeship

Use Heroku and Codeship for our CI. Have been creating a web-app in Angular using Protractor for testing. Everything runs fine locally, but when it gets to CI, some of the tests will fail. The weird thing is, the failing ones are random: sometimes they will fail, then refreshing the build makes them pass again. Here's the error code:

```
Running "protractor:your_target" (protractor) task Starting selenium standalone server... [launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver Selenium standalone server started at http://10.0.3.170:40348/wd/hub .....F..F....  Failures:  1) Application Filter should sort stores by number 0-9 Message: Error: Index out of bound. Trying to access element at index: 0, but there are only 0 elements that match locator By.cssSelector(".name") Stacktrace: Error: Index out of bound. Trying to access element at index: 0, but there are only 0 elements that match locator By.cssSelector(".name") ==== async task ==== Asynchronous test function: it() Error at [object Object].<anonymous> (/home/rof/src/github.com/DigitalInnovation/staffdirectory/test/e2e/app.js:83:34) Error at [object Object].<anonymous> (/home/rof/src/github.com/DigitalInnovation/staffdirectory/test/e2e/app.js:76:9) at [object Object].<anonymous> (/home/rof/src/github.com/DigitalInnovation/staffdirectory/test/e2e/app.js:50:5) at Object.<anonymous> (/home/rof/src/github.com/DigitalInnovation/staffdirectory/test/e2e/app.js:3:1)  2) Application Store Name And Number should show 4 store numbers Message: Expected 0 to be 4. Stacktrace: Error: Failed expectation at [object Object].<anonymous> (/home/rof/src/github.com/DigitalInnovation/staffdirectory/test/e2e/app.js:112:34)  Finished in 42.619 seconds 13 tests, 19 assertions, 2 failures  Shutting down selenium standalone server. [launcher] 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running [launcher] chrome #1 failed 2 test(s) [launcher] overall: 2 failed spec(s) [launcher] Process exited with error code 1 >>  Fatal error: protractor exited with code: 1
```

Here's my app.js file with the tests:

```
    var env = require('./mockservice.js');

describe("Application", function() {
    var ptor;
    beforeEach(function() {
        ptor = browser;
        ptor.addMockModule('MockServicesModule', env.httpBackendMock);
        ptor.ignoreSynchronization = false;
        browser.get('/');
        ptor.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        ptor.sleep(1000);
    });

    it('should verify the title', function() {
        ptor.getTitle().then(function(title) {
            expect(title).toBe('Store Directory');
        });
    });

    describe("Search Bar", function() {

        it('should enable input of data and return search result in list instantly', function() {
            var searchBar = element.all(by.css('.store_text'));
            searchBar.click();
            searchBar.sendKeys("argyle");
            var name = element.all(by.css('.name'));
            expect(name.get(0).getText()).toEqual('Argyle St. Glasgow');
            var number = element.all(by.css('.number'));
            expect(number.get(0).getText()).toEqual('657');
        });

        it('should allow deletion of data that should instantly return all stores', function() {
            var searchBar = element.all(by.css('.store_text'));
            searchBar.click();
            searchBar.sendKeys("argyle");
            ptor.sleep(1000);
            searchBar.sendKeys(protractor.Key.BACK_SPACE);
            searchBar.sendKeys(protractor.Key.BACK_SPACE);
            searchBar.sendKeys(protractor.Key.BACK_SPACE);
            searchBar.sendKeys(protractor.Key.BACK_SPACE);
            searchBar.sendKeys(protractor.Key.BACK_SPACE);
            searchBar.sendKeys(protractor.Key.BACK_SPACE);
            var name = element.all(by.css('.name'));
            expect(name.get(0).getText()).toEqual('Aberdeen');
            var number = element.all(by.css('.number'));
            expect(number.get(0).getText()).toEqual('2587');
        });
    });

    describe("Filter", function() {

        it('should sort stores by name a-z', function() {
            var filterBtn = element.all(by.css('.sort_text'));
            filterBtn.click();
            var azButton = element.all(by.cssContainingText('option', 'Stores A-Z'));
            azButton.click();
            ptor.sleep(1000);
            var nameaz = element.all(by.css('.name'));
            expect(nameaz.get(0).getText()).toEqual('Aberdeen');
            var numberaz = element.all(by.css('.number'));
            expect(numberaz.get(0).getText()).toEqual('2587');
        });

        it('should sort stores by name z-a', function() {
            var filterBtn = element.all(by.css('.sort_text'));
            filterBtn.click();
            var zaButton = element.all(by.cssContainingText('option', 'Stores Z-A'));
            zaButton.click();
            ptor.sleep(1000);
            var nameza = element.all(by.css('.name'));
            expect(nameza.get(0).getText()).toEqual('Ayr');
            var numberza = element.all(by.css('.number'));
            expect(numberza.get(0).getText()).toEqual('2024');
        });

        it('should sort stores by number 0-9', function() {
            var filterBtn = element.all(by.css('.sort_text'));
            filterBtn.click();
            var noButton = element.all(by.cssContainingText('option', 'Store Number 0-9'));
            noButton.click();
            ptor.sleep(1000);
            var name09 = element.all(by.css('.name'));
            expect(name09.get(0).getText()).toEqual('Anniesland');
            var number09 = element.all(by.css('.number'));
            expect(number09.get(0).getText()).toEqual('397');
        });

        it('should sort stores by number 9-0', function() {
            var filterBtn = element.all(by.css('.sort_text'));
            filterBtn.click();
            var noButton = element.all(by.cssContainingText('option', 'Store Number 9-0'));
            noButton.click();
            ptor.sleep(1000);
            var name90 = element.all(by.css('.name'));
            expect(name90.get(0).getText()).toEqual('Aberdeen');
            var number90 = element.all(by.css('.number'));
            expect(number90.get(0).getText()).toEqual('2587');
        });
    });

    describe("Store Name And Number", function() {

        it('should show 4 store names', function() {
        var names = element.all(by.repeater('store in stores'));
        ptor.sleep(1000);
        expect(names.count()).toBe(4);
        });

        it('should show 4 store numbers', function() {
        var number04 = element.all(by.repeater('store in stores'));
        ptor.sleep(1000);
        expect(number04.count()).toBe(4);
        });

        it('should show details of the store roles and numbers when either the store name or store number is clicked on', function () {
            var label = element.all(by.id('label')).first();
            label.click();
            ptor.sleep(1000);
            var roles = element.all(by.repeater('contact in storeInfo.contacts'));
            expect(roles.count()).toBe(2);
        });

        it('should close back to the main list after expanding more store details', function () {
            var label = element.all(by.id('label')).first();
            label.click();
            ptor.sleep(1000);
            label.click();
            ptor.sleep(1000);
            var stores = element.all(by.repeater('store in stores'));
            expect(stores.count()).toBe(4);
        });
    });

    describe("Store search", function() {

        it('should show search results instantly', function() {
            var label = element.all(by.id('label')).first();
            label.click();
            ptor.sleep(1000);
            var storeSearch = element.all(by.css('.role_text'));
            storeSearch.click();
            ptor.sleep(1000);
            storeSearch.sendKeys("service");
            ptor.sleep(1000);
            var roles = element.all(by.repeater('contact in storeInfo.contacts'));
            expect(roles.count()).toBe(1);
        });

        it('should allow deletion of data to show an unfiltered list of roles', function() {
            var label = element.all(by.id('label')).get(1);
            label.click();
            ptor.sleep(1000);
            var storeSearch = element.all(by.css('.role_text'));
            storeSearch.click();
            ptor.sleep(1000);
            storeSearch.sendKeys("cold");
            ptor.sleep(1000);
            var roles = element.all(by.repeater('contact in storeInfo.contacts'));
            expect(roles.count()).toBe(1);
            storeSearch.sendKeys(protractor.Key.BACK_SPACE);
            storeSearch.sendKeys(protractor.Key.BACK_SPACE);
            storeSearch.sendKeys(protractor.Key.BACK_SPACE);
            storeSearch.sendKeys(protractor.Key.BACK_SPACE);
            ptor.sleep(1000);
            expect(roles.count()).toBe(2);
        });
    });
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated. The 'index out of bound' error I thought could be fixed with more sleep, but don't have a clue about the other one...we are using mock data for these tests.